# Characters substitutions in predicates

Tags: ios, predicate

I'm looking for an efficient method to do queries on core data strings that have character representations that may have changed over historical periods or could be represented multiple ways. Consider Norwegian, for example, where `aa` and `å` are equivalent or where `ae` and `æ` are equivalent. Is there an efficient way to allow a user to type in just one of these options and return results that match both?

For example, if the database included the names `Amy`, `Sæthre`, `Saethre`, `Langås` a query of `"a"` should return all four. A query of `"æ"` should return `Sæthre` and `Saethre`, as should a query of `"ae"`. A query of `"aa"` should return `Langås` but none of the others.

Comment: There is NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption, e.g.: "naïve" like[d] "naive"

see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscomparisonpredicateoptions/nsdiacriticinsensitivepredicateoption

But if that works for you, depends on the "mapping" of those norwegian characters.

Comment: Yes, I know about case sensitivity and diacritic sensitivity, but these are not diacritics or case. Note that one version has one character, and another has two.

Comment: SQLite has a `replace()` function that would do what I want, and Core Data has SQLite as a back end, but I don't know if it's possible to use the `replace()` function in `NSPredicate`.